# Multiple `awk` statements with pipes `|` ?

Tags: linux, awk, regular-expression

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash  
#### Extract OS-related info from a Linux box  #### 

#### Display header message ####
# $1 - message

function write_header(){
    local h="$@"
    echo "------------------------------"
    echo "  ${h}"
    echo "------------------------------"
}

#### Get info about Operating System ####

function  os_info(){
    write_header "System Info"
    echo "Operating System : $(uname --kernel-name)" #uname -s 
    echo "Kernel Version   : $(uname --kernel-release)"  #uname -r 
    awk '/^NAME=/||/^VERSION=/' /etc/os-release    
}
```

In the above code, I can extract specific fields from `uname` and `/etc/os-release` that looks like this:

```
System Info
------------------------------
Operating System : Linux
Kernel Version   : 3.16.0-4-amd64
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
```

What I haven't been able to do, though is to add an `awk` pipe like this, e.g.: `awk -F'=' '{print $2}`, to the original `awk` statement. I'd like for output that looks like this for the last two lines: `NAME: Debain GNU/Linux` and `VERSION: 8 (jessie)`.

Any suggestions on how to combine the awk statements to achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'[="]+' '/^(NAME|VERSION)=/{printf("%-17s: %s\n",$1,$2)}' /etc/os-release
```

produce

```
NAME             : BunsenLabs GNU/Linux
VERSION          : 8.6 (Hydrogen)
```

Comment: That works EXACTLY as I'd like. Could you explain this portion: `{printf("%-17s: %s\n",$1,$2)}` of the code?

Comment: @marshki `man 3 printf`: "***%-17s: %s\n***" — use format( "**-**" left justified, "**17**" field wide, "**s**" field in string format, "**:** " as is, "**%s**" next field in string format, "**\n**" new line), "**$1,$2**" list fields to print

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the regex matching:

```
awk -F= '$1 == "NAME" || $1 == "VERSION" {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to work for me:

```
awk -F'=' '/^NAME=/||/^VERSION=/ { print $2 }' /etc/os-release
```

Input:

```
~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Output:

```
~$ awk -F'=' '/^NAME=/||/^VERSION=/ { print $2 }' /etc/os-release
"Ubuntu"
"16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
```

Comment: Could you share the output of that command? I get this:                        `./os_info.sh: line 22: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''`
`./os_info.sh: line 28: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: Certainly.  Done and done.

Comment: sure.  just add `| sed 's/"//g'` after the `awk` line.